How to find a covariant gauge derivative from a field transformation
For reference: I'm self-studying from Peskin's Particle Physics 2019, which tries to sweep all QFT under the rug.
Consider an SU(3) gauge theory; I am told a $3\times 3$ scalar field $\Phi$ transforms under SU(3) as $$\Phi\rightarrow\Phi+(i\alpha^at^a)\Phi+\Phi(-i\alpha^at^a)$$ for generators $t^a$ (Gell-Mann matrices) and coupling constant $g$. I am asked to find the covariant derivative acting on $\Phi$, but I'm a little lost and the book doesn't explicitly show me how to do so.
Citing a previous problem's result stated in the text, my best guess is $$D_\mu\Phi=\partial_\mu\Phi+(-igA_\mu^at^a)\Phi+\Phi(+igA_\mu^at^a)$$ but I'm not sure (if this is right) where it would come from.
This looks like it has something to do with commutators, something like if $$\Phi\rightarrow\Phi+[i\alpha^at^a,\Phi],$$ then $$D_\mu\Phi=\partial_\mu\Phi -ig[A_\mu t^a,\Phi]$$.
However, if this were true, how would one even consider the simplest case of U(1) gauge group in which $D_\mu\phi=\partial_\mu\Phi -ieQA_\mu\phi$, which corresponds to a phase transformation $\phi\rightarrow e^{i\beta}\phi\ $?

I'll give the example for SU(N):
Consider a field $\Phi$ in the fundamental representation of SU(N) which means that $\Phi \to U \Phi$, with $U \in SU(N)$. Now consider how its ordinary derivative would transform
\begin{equation}
 \partial_\mu \Phi \to \partial_\mu(U \Phi) = U \partial_\mu \Phi + \Phi \partial_\mu U
\end{equation}
This does not transform covariantly. Thus, let's introduce a covariant derivative such that it actually does transform covariantly
\begin{equation}
 D_\mu \Phi \to U D_\mu \Phi
\end{equation}
Then it can be figured out what $D_\mu$ should look like, namely make the ansatz
\begin{equation}
 D_\mu = \partial_\mu - W_\mu,
\end{equation}
because the second term needs to be something that has a Lorentz index as well.
Then we need to figure out how $W_\mu$ should transform in order for the covariant derivative to be covariant. So, consider
\begin{align}
 \partial_\mu \Phi - D_\mu \Phi &\to U(\partial_\mu \Phi) + (\partial_\mu U) \Phi - U D_\mu \Phi \\
&= U(\partial_\mu \Phi) + (\partial_\mu U) \Phi - U \partial_\mu \Phi + U W_\mu \Phi \\
&= (U W_\mu U^{-1} + (\partial_\mu U)U^{-1}) U \Phi
\end{align}
This tells us that $W_\mu$ is an element of the adjoint representation and can be written as a sum over the generators $W_\mu = \alpha^a_\mu t_a$. I leave it to you to make the adjustments if you have a coupling constant $g$ and if you redefine the generators by $i$.
Now, the above is for the fundamental representation. For the adjoint representation we have generally
\begin{equation}
D_\mu = \partial_\mu - [W_\mu,.].
\end{equation}
You can figure this out analogously to what I wrote before, but now for a field in the adjoint which transforms as $\Phi \to U \Phi U^{-1}$ such that we want a covariant derivative transforming as $D_\mu \Phi \to U(D_\mu \Phi)U^{-1}$.
So if in your case $\Phi = \Phi^a t_a$ and is group-valued, then
\begin{equation}
D_\mu \Phi = \partial_\mu \Phi - [W_\mu,\Phi] = \partial_\mu \Phi - \alpha^a_\mu \Phi^b[t_a,t_b].
\end{equation}
